# Snowflake Flatten JSON Multiple Arrays

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, json-flattener

I'm receiving multiple JSON files and loading them into a Snowflake variant field. I would like to then extract some of the child arrays into a separate table but am having issues with that. Here is an example of the JSON:

```
{
  "ordernumber": 123,
  "customername": "Smith,John",
  "orderdata": {
    "Order": {
      "ItemCountGroup": {
        "items": {
          "item": [
            {
              "ItemCount": "1.00"
            },
            {
              "ItemCount": "1.00"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "ItemDescGroup": {
        "items": {
          "item": [
            {
              "ItemDesc": "Series 100 Food Bucket"
            },
            {
              "ItemDesc": "Series X Leather Gloves"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "ItemTypeGroup": {
        "items": {
          "item": [
            {
              "ItemType": "Bucket/Pail"
            },
            {
              "ItemType": "Gloves"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to flatten the table so that it comes out:

| ItemCount | ItemDesc | ItemType | OrderNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.00 | Series 100 Food Bucket | Bucket/Pail | 123 |
| 1.00 | Series X Leather Gloves | Gloves | 123 |

I've tried a series of different flatten commands and lateral flattens but usually am getting a row for every combination possible between each of the elements. Is there a way or example out there for me to get these into the required format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table named `T1` with your JSON in a variant column named `V`, you can flatten each part in a CTE and join them by the index created during the flattening:

```
with ItemCountGroup as
(
select v:ordernumber ORDERNUMBER, INDEX IDX, VALUE:ItemCount::number(38,2) ITEM_COUNT from T1, 
    table(flatten(v:orderdata.Order.ItemCountGroup.items.item))
),
ItemDescriptionGroup as
(
select INDEX IDX, VALUE:ItemDesc::string ITEM_DESC from T1, 
    table(flatten(v:orderdata.Order.ItemDescGroup.items.item))
),
ItemTypeGroup as
(
select INDEX IDX, VALUE:ItemType::string ITEM_TYPE from T1, 
    table(flatten(v:orderdata.Order.ItemTypeGroup.items.item))
)
select ITEM_COUNT, ITEM_DESC, ITEM_TYPE, ORDERNUMBER
from ItemCountGroup IC
    left join ItemDescriptionGroup ID on IC.IDX = ID.IDX
    left join ItemTypeGroup IT on IC.IDX = IT.IDX
;
```

| ITEM_COUNT | ITEM_DESC | ITEM_TYPE | ORDERNUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Series 100 Food Bucket | Bucket/Pail | 123 |
| 1 | Series X Leather Gloves | Gloves | 123 |

Comment: That worked well.  I had to tweak it a bit because each order had a different number of items (they are not consistent) and adding the Order Number to criteria solved that. Is there a good way to add the Order Number (ordernumber) as a column?

Comment: You can just project the ordernumber on any one of the table expressions to join. I updated the answer to show this.

Comment: Thanks, I had to add order number to each of the select statements and use that as part of the join criteria as well which solved the issue.  Appreciate the help!